# how to fix Error:Execution failed for task ': duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrq$1.class

Tags: android, google-places-api

I need to use code for google map places but i faced this crash when I add
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
How to fix it ?
this is my dependencies:

```
     dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

}
```

Comment: remove one of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'`. play-services:9.4.0' is a complete pack of services, :play-services-gcm:9.8.0 includes only GSM services, which are also included in  play-services:9.4.0'

Comment: I removed 9.8.0 but it still the same error !!

Comment: you also use `play-services-maps` the same way. I think that error message differs now.

Comment: i removed play-services-maps and got this error "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzrq$1.class"

Comment: @alsalimi do u have any jars in your lib folder?

Comment: No I don't have

Answer (score 0):

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'` and add this snippet to app's `build.gredle`

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/gson/FieldAttributes.class'
        exclude '.readme'

    }
}
```

Or you can add this line to the file `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-dontwarn com.google.**
```

May be this solve your problem, or let me know.